Title Bar Disappears in HeidiSQL(Wine) with Dark Mode on Ubuntu 24.04
New to Ubuntu 24.04, I recently installed HeidiSQL using Wine after switching from Windows. I successfully imported my database connections, but I encountered an issue when switching to dark mode. The title bar of HeidiSQL disappears with any theme other than the default (Windows), and the title bar of the application behind HeidiSQL becomes visible, leading to accidental closures.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
